# Sequelize create object with associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to save sequelize models with their associations. All the associations are one to one. Retrieving models with associations from the database works just fine but inserting them is another matter and the documentation is just making me more confused.

Here's my insert method:

```
models
    .radcheck
    .create(user, {
        include: [{model: models.skraningar}, {model: models.radusergroup}, {model: models.radippool}]
        })
    .then(success, error);
```

I've seen so many ways to do this both in the documentation and here on stackoverflow and none of them make sense to me so far. Anyone care to clear things up for me?

Comment: Are you trying to create a radcheck object, while at the same time, creating skraningar, radusergroup and radippool?

Comment: Thats right. Isn't that possible with sequelize?

Comment: No, I don't think so, it would involve multiple insert statements which would not be done with a single .create() call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always save a model with association by it's foreign key

e.g

```
models.user.create({ name : 'test', usergroup_id : 1 });
```

Comment: But doesn’t that kind of go one level of abstraction deeper than one might want to?

Comment: this solution also works if the 1 model is usergroup and N model is user, got it?