# How do I reference an association when creating a row in sequelize without assuming the foreign key column name?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:file.sqlite');

var User = sequelize.define('User', { email: Sequelize.STRING});
var Thing = sequelize.define('Thing', { name: Sequelize.STRING});
Thing.belongsTo(User);

sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  return User.create({email: 'asdf@example.org'});
}).then(function (user) {
  return Thing.create({
    name: 'A thing',
    User: user
  }, {
    include: [User]
  });
}).then(function (thing) {
  return Thing.findOne({where: {id: thing.id}, include: [User]});
}).then(function (thing) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(thing));
});
```

I get the following output:

```
ohnobinki@gibby ~/public_html/turbocase1 $ ./sqltest.js
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (NULL,'asdf@example.org','2015-12-03 06:11:36.904 +00:00','2015-12-03 06:11:36.904 +00:00');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'asdf@example.org','2015-12-03 06:11:36.904 +00:00','2015-12-03 06:11:37.022 +00:00');
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
    at Query.formatError (/home/ohnobinki/public_html/turbocase1/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:231:14)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (/home/ohnobinki/public_html/turbocase1/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:47:29)
    at Statement.replacement (/home/ohnobinki/public_html/turbocase1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:20:31)
```

It seems that specifying `{include: [User]}` instructs Sequelize to create a new `User` instance matching the contents of `user`. That is not my goal. In fact, I find it hard to believe that such behaviour would ever be useful—I at least have no use for it. I want to be able to have a long-living `User` record in the database and at arbitrary times create new `Thing`s which refer to the `User`. In my shown example, I wait for the `User` to be created, but in actual code it would likely have been freshly loaded through `User.findOne()`.

I have seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29995868/429091) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28160882/429091) say that I have to explicitly specify the implicitly-created `UserId` column in my `Thing.create()` call. When Sequelize provides an API like `Thing.belongsTo(User)`, I *shouldn’t* have to be aware of the fact that a `Thing.UserId` field is created. So **what is the clean API-respecting way of creating a new `Thing` which refers to a particular `User` without having to guess the name of the `UserId` field?** When I load a `Thing` and specify `{include: [User]}`, I access the loaded user through the `thing.User` property. I don’t think I’m supposed to know about or try to access a `thing.UserId` field. In my `Thing.belongsTo(User)` call, I never specify `UserId`, I just treat that like an implementation detail I shouldn’t care about. How can I continue to avoid caring about that implementation detail when creating a `Thing`?

The `Thing.create()` call that works but looks wrong to me:

```
Thing.create({
  name: 'A thing',
  UserId: user.id
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - risks DB inconsistency**

Sequelize dynamically generates methods for setting associations on instances, e.g. `thing.setUser(user);`. In your use case:

```
sequelize.sync({force: true})
.then(function () {
  return Promise.all([
    User.create({email: 'asdf@example.org'}),
    Thing.create({name: 'A thing'})  
  ]);
})
.spread(function(user, thing) {
  return thing.setUser(user);
})
.then(function(thing) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(thing));
});
```

**Option 2 - does not work/buggy**

It isn't documented, but from a code dive I think the following should work. It doesn't but that seems to be because of a couple of bugs:

```
// ...
.then(function () {
  return models.User.create({email: 'asdf@example.org'});
})
.then(function(user) {
  // Fails with SequelizeUniqueConstraintError - the User instance inherits isNewRecord from the Thing instance, but it has already been saved
  return models.Thing.create({
    name: 'thingthing',
    User: user
  }, {
    include: [{
      model: models.User
    }],
    fields: ['name'] // seems nec to specify all non-included fields because of line 277 in instance.js - another bug?
  });
})
```

Replacing `models.User.create` with `models.User.build` doesn't work because the built but not saved instance's primary key is null. `Instance#_setInclude` ignores the instance if its primary key is null.

**Option 3**

Wrapping the Thing's `create` in a transaction prevents an inconsistent state.

```
sq.sync({ force: true })
.then(models.User.create.bind(models.User, { email: 'asdf@example.org' }))
.then(function(user) {
  return sq.transaction(function(tr) {
    return models.Thing.create({name: 'A thing'})
    .then(function(thing) { return thing.setUser(user); });
  });
})
.then(print_result.bind(null, 'Thing with User...'))
.catch(swallow_rejected_promise.bind(null, 'main promise chain'))
.finally(function() {
  return sq.close();
});
```

I have uploaded a script demo'ing option 2 and option 3 [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/15-build-with-associations)

Comment: But this would do an `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE` and make it possible for the `Thing` to be created without a `User` set on it if the program terminated before `setUser()` is resolved. I think I am missing specifying `NOT NULL` in the relationship definition, but that is kind of beside the point of my question.

Comment: Gotcha - I've expanded my answer to include another couple of approaches that should guarantee consistency. Option 2 doesn't work but I think that's because of a bug.

Comment: Update: From https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3807#issuecomment-105764373 it looks like Sequelize currently only supports full creates. It's not clear if these can be done without specifying the foreign key column name explicitly.

Comment: Option 2 is not really different from what I’m doing right now, AFAICT ;-). Looks like from the issue you reference that what I want isn’t yet supported.

It looks like, with the current state of Sequelize, I will have to use option 3, transactions, to get the behavior I want. Two questions about your current option 3:

1. Could the creation of `User` be prior to the transaction (to better match the workflow I’m going for)?
2. Does the transaction actually work when you never reference `tr`? I will verify the behavior myself a minute…

Comment: I have edited option 3 in the above to create the user outside the transaction and pushed an updated test script to github. In my test script it isn't necessary to explicitly refer to the transaction and passing {transaction: tr} to the create and setUser call does not change the commands issued to the DB.

Comment: So, seems the ideal way isn’t supported by sequelize yet. The transaction option is OK and technically answers the question because I didn’t specify that the key field would be `NOT NULL` (which I haven’t tried to do yet).

Answer (score 1):

Tested on `sequelize@6.5.1 sqlite3@5.0.2` I can use `User.associations.Comments.foreignKey` as in:

```
const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
User.hasMany(Comment)
Comment.belongsTo(User)
console.dir(User);
await sequelize.sync({force: true});
const u0 = await User.create({name: 'u0'})
const u1 = await User.create({name: 'u1'})
await Comment.create({body: 'u0c0', [User.associations.Comments.foreignKey]: u0.id});
```

The association is also returned during creation, so you could also:

```
const Comments = User.hasMany(Comment)
await Comment.create({body: 'u0c0', [Comments.foreignKey]: u0.id});
```

and on many-to-many through tables you get `foreignKey` and `otherKey` for the second foreign key.

`User.associations.Comments.foreignKey` contains the `foreignKey` `UserId`.

Or analogously with aliases:

```
User.hasMany(Post, {as: 'authoredPosts', foreignKey: 'authorId'});
Post.belongsTo(User, {as: 'author', foreignKey: 'authorId'});

User.hasMany(Post, {as: 'reviewedPosts', foreignKey: 'reviewerId'});
Post.belongsTo(User, {as: 'reviewer', foreignKey: 'reviewerId'});
await sequelize.sync({force: true});

// Create data.
const users = await User.bulkCreate([
  {name: 'user0'},
  {name: 'user1'},
])

const posts = await Post.bulkCreate([
  {body: 'body00', authorId: users[0].id, reviewerId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body01', [User.associations.authoredPosts.foreignKey]: users[0].id, 
                   [User.associations.reviewedPosts.foreignKey]: users[1].id},
])
```

But that syntax is so long that I'm tempted to just hardcode the keys everywhere.